# Convert Digraph to StringIO with graphviz

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphviz, image-graphviz

Does anyone know a trick how to convert a `Digraph` into a `io.StringIO` png? The only code I could find is to save it to disk, but I would like to leave out any disk usage and to process it in memory instead:

```
from graphviz import Digraph
import io

dot = Digraph(comment='The Round Table')
dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')

# instead of this...
dot.render('test-output/round-table.gv', view=True)

# ... I need something like this:
data = io.StringIO()
dot.export_to_png(dot)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
from graphviz import Digraph
import io

dot = Digraph(comment='The Round Table', format='gv')
dot.node('A', 'King Arthur')

data = io.StringIO()

print("writing")
data.write( dot.pipe().decode('utf-8') )

print("reading")
data.seek(0)
print(data.read())

# print(data.getvalue())


data.close()
```

Comment: Perfect! That's it. But just wondering, some characters might be not available in utf-8, so I just used latin-1 instead and `pipe(format="png")` instead. Anyway, that worked perfectly! Thanks